# Why so many headset spacers on some expedition bicycles?

Tags: touring

I've been looking at expedition bikes and I've noticed on some bikes I've seen that they have a lot of headset spacers such as http://www.oxfordbikeworks.co.uk/models/overview/ and thorn cycles in particular. Why is that?

Comment: more spacers = higher handlebars = greater angle between your legs and torso = more upright = more comfortable [= less aerodynamic]. Or so the theory goes.

Comment: why not design a frame with a longer headtube then?

Comment: flexibility? But I'm sure if you look around you'll see variation in head tube length too.

Comment: I'm just curious because back in 07 when I put together a touring bike using a mtb frame, I ended up using a lot of spacers, which at the time I thought wasn't a good thing, because the frame wasn't designed for it, and I also decided later that the frame was also too small. Plus since then I've use an adjustable stem instead. Maybe there is a benefit of smaller frame diamond segments for strength?

Comment: It also allows the production of a fewer number of sizes and allows for more adjustment (since you can always cut the steerer tube later).

Comment: One guess is as its easy to lower bars on a long stem than raise them on a short stem - having a lot of spacers means bikes ship ex factory with a stem length that means handle bar height can be adjusted to suit a wide range of rider preferences. Something that can be done with just an Allan key.

Comment: all good points there. On this model http://www.oxfordbikeworks.co.uk/models/model-1e the number of spacers looks obscene, but its not mentioned why. If you were a tall rider why not just buy a bigger frame? I suppose it might give you more stepover clearance which could be a benefit if you are stopping often and have a loaded bike.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having received an answer from Oxford:

> As regards spacers, cycle tourists want/need a low stand over height,
>   so that their bikes handle nicely and so that they can stop easily and
>   grip their bike between their thighs when fully loaded. However, many
>   cycle tourists want a head-up relatively high front end so that they
>   can see into the middle distance without getting a stiff neck. For
>   those cyclists who come from a road/700c background, they typically
>   want a lower handlebar setting at the front, so the number of spacers
>   is less, so generally its not an issue.